# How to implement onClickListener on imageList

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `ArrayList<ImageView>` in a fragment. That list contains some images that animate over a period of time. I want to increment my score each time user clicks on the image. How can i achieve that?

**ImageArray**

```
private fun getArray() = arrayListOf(kennyPos0,kennyPos1,kennyPos2,kennyPos3,kennyPos4,
            kennyPos5,kennyPos6,kennyPos7,kennyPos8)
```

**This function animates it.**

```
    private fun manipulateImage() {

        runnable = Runnable {
            for (image in getArray()) {
                image.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
            val randomNum = Random()
            val index = randomNum.nextInt(8-0)
            getArray()[index].visibility = View.VISIBLE
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,500)
        }
        handler.post(runnable)
    }
```

**How do i write the onClickListener?**

```
    private fun incrementScore(v:View) {
            score++
            v.scoreText.text = "Score :$score"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array you create and add the listeners at any time. Even though your code is not entirely clear, you might do it where you set the items are invisible at first.

```
for (image in getArray()) {
    image.apply {
        visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        setOnClickListener { 
            incrementScore(this)
        }
    }
}
```